# ng2-order-pipe doesn't sort after adding/removing objects

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

In my application, I am displaying a div for each object in my array and using the ng2-order-pipe to sort them:

```
<div class="patients-container" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" (drop)="onDrop($event)">
  <div class="patient-box" draggable="true" *ngFor="let patient of patients | orderBy: order" (dragstart)="onDrag($event, patient)">
    <table class="patient-table">
    <th class="location-header">
      <p class="location" (click)="openEditPatientDialog(patient)">{{patient.location}}<md-icon>edit</md-icon></p>
      <p class="name" [style.visibility]="patient.name == '' ? 'hidden' : 'visible'">{{patient.name}}</p>
      <p class="triage"><md-icon [style.color]="patient.severity">favorite</md-icon></p>
    </th>
    <th class="intervals-header"> 
      <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let interval of intervals">
          <td>{{interval}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
     </th>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

When my application starts they are sorted. However, because it is possible to drag and drop these div's, I am moving the objects back and forth between two components. When I move an object to the other component and then back, the div's aren't sorted anymore and I will have to click on my sort button again.

Is there any way to make it automatically sort the objects again when objects get added to the array? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with **pure** property as below:

Look at here for more details: https://blog.khophi.co/ionic-2-filter-templates-pipes/

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({ name: 'orderBy', pure: true })
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(array: Array<any>, orderField: string, orderType: boolean): Array<string> {
        array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
            if (a[orderField] == null || a[orderField].isUndefined) return orderType ? 0 - b[orderField] : b[orderField] - 0;
            if (b[orderField] == null || b[orderField].isUndefined) return orderType ? a[orderField] - 0 : b[orderField] - 0;
            return orderType ? a[orderField] - b[orderField] : b[orderField] - a[orderField];
        });
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not tried that. Since I got the pipe through NPM, I am not sure how to change it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating my own custom `impure` pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy',
  pure: false
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: Array<any>, orderProperty: string): Array<any> {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[orderProperty] < b[orderProperty]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[orderProperty] > b[orderProperty]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }

}
```

Apparently, ng2-order-pipe is a pure pipe, and pure pipes get executed only when pure changes are detected, eg. changed primitive input values or changed object references. In my case, I am using the same array all the way, so when I add new objects to it, the reference to my array is still the same and thus the pipe will not be executed. You can read more about pure and impure pipes here: https://angular.io/guide/pipes